# I want to find duplicate data from the database and show sum of duplicate data in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get all the data from SALES and PURCHASES table but I want to show product name for the single time and also want to show the sum of its quanitity..

How can i do this in laravel 8 ?

What will be the query ??

```
$stock = DB::table('products')
        ->join('purchases','purchases.product_id','products.id')
        ->join('sales','sales.product_id','products.id')
        ->groupBy('product_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have your whole query but use havingRaw to find the duplicates.

```php
$dups = DB::table('tableName')
->select('col1_name','colX_name', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
->join('purchases','purchases.product_id','products.id')
->join('sales','sales.product_id','products.id')
->groupBy('col1_name', 'ColX_name')
->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 1')
->get();
```

Comment: What is the Meaning of col1_name and ColX_name ??

Comment: @SwapnilMane It means: column name

Comment: But which column name. I have updated the code sir.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that

```
 $stock = DB::table('products')
            ->select('sales.*','purchases.*','products.name', DB::raw('products.name as `NbProduct`'))
            ->join('purchases','purchases.product_id','products.id')
            ->join('sales','sales.product_id','products.id')
            ->groupBy('sales.id', purchases.id)
            ->get();
```